# Is it possible to write a cron expression that runs at different times each given day of week?

Tags: amazon-web-services, time, cron, aws-lambda

Please note, that the format I'm using starts with minutes and excludes seconds. According to the AWS requirements.

So, let's say I need a cron expression to run a Cloud Event at Monday and Sunday on 15:00, that would look like *this*:

`0 15 * * MON,SUN *`

That should work perfectly. But now let's say I need to run a lambda on every Monday on 15:00, and every Sunday on 17:00. Or even twice on Monday - 15:00 and 22:00, and 17:00 on Sunday. Is that possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

Because of the way CRON is built and the expressions are set up:
[image: CRON Expression Breakdown]

You will most likely need to have multiple CRON jobs scheduled to do what you want to do. I don't think you will be able to get that complex of a schedule built into a single expression.